# Search and Replace Columns using Full Text Search Mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Is there a way of running a Mysql Query using Full Text Search that will search a column for example (hayes) and replace the rest of the string with "hayes" once matched?:

Column1:
london, hayes, MD15 736

```
WHERE MATCH (COLUMN1) AGAINST ('hayes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Column1:
hayes

So since column 1 has matched "hayes" its removed the rest of the string. It needs to be done by full text as like for example takes too long on large data sets.

And there is no set order where the keyword maybe so i cannot use `find_in_set`

Also i will running this with a large number of keywords like the below:

```
WHERE MATCH (COLUMN1) AGAINST ('hayes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH (COLUMN1) AGAINST ('+WEST +BROMWICH' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH (COLUMN1) AGAINST ('London' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

So if i run the above query on a column1 which contains the following string:

`london, m456, hayes` <<< it would match hayes ONLY and not both london and hayes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try  Find rows that contain at least one of the two words.

```
     AGAINST ('+hayes +London' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

if you want to find row that contain both words then use this

```
    AGAINST ('+hayes London' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

EDIT:

```
UPDATE table
SET COLUMN1 =
        'HAYES'
 WHERE
  COLUMN1
 LIKE
    '%hayes%';
```

if you have more keywords use like that

```
   UPDATE table
   SET COLUMN1 =if(
    COLUMN1 LIKE '%hayes%', 'HAYAS', if( 
    COLUMN1 LIKE '%derby%' ,'DERBY' , if(
    COLUMN1 LIKE '%wawwaw%' ,'WAWAWA', Column1)))
```

Comment: I already know this i need to be able to replace the whole string with the keyword when its matched do you know how i can do this?

Comment: i didnt understan what you mean , give example pls

Comment: No sorry what i mean is i want to do a search and replace function on the column so if it matches "hayes" it replaces the whole column removing everything and leaving just Hayes in that column

Comment: Excellent this works how can i run this on multiple keywords can i do or set? UPDATE table
SET COLUMN1 = 'HAYES' WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '%hayes%' or SET COLUMN1 = 'derby' WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '%derby%' << would this work? Thanks again. God bless.

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work i get the following error:

#1054 - Unknown column 'HAYES' in 'field list'